# (Angular upgrade) AngularJS component's binding should be undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-upgrade

Currently trying to figure out why this happens, but if I have an optionnal function binding (`&?`) on a NG1 component then NG2 will put a EventEmitter on it :/

This is not what I expect and breaks some code we do when these are normally `null`/`undefined`.

Here is a example of what we have :

```
class MyController {
  public onInit: () => string;
  public onAction: () => void;

  public resultFromNg2: string;
  public onActionHasValue: boolean;
  public typeOfOnAction: string;

  public $onInit() {
    this.resultFromNg2 = this.onInit();
    this.onActionHasValue = this.onAction != null;
    this.typeOfOnAction = typeof this.onAction;
  }
}

export const ng1DemoComponent = {
  selector: "ng1-demo",
  template: `
    <div>Hello, {{ $ctrl.username }}!</div>
    <div>resultFromNg2: {{ $ctrl.resultFromNg2 }}</div>
    <div>onActionHasValue: {{ $ctrl.onActionHasValue }} - typeof: {{ $ctrl.typeOfOnAction }}</div>
  `,
  bindings: {
    username: "<",
    onInit: "&?",
    onAction: "&?"
  },
  controller: MyController
};

@Directive({
  selector: ng1DemoComponent.selector
})
export class Ng1DemoComponentFacade extends UpgradeComponent {
  @Input() username: string;
  @Input() onInit: () => string;
  @Input() onAction: () => void;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
    super(ng1DemoComponent.selector, elementRef, injector);
  }
}
```

Testable environment : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hybrid-upgrade-dpjv4p?file=ng1%2Fng1-demo.component.ts

In this code, I expect to have `onAction` set to `undefined` so I can assign my other property properly, but currently it's not working :/

I also tried removing the `?`, so from `&?` to `&`, but now it's NG1 who gives probably `angular.noop` ..

Any ideas on how I can make this work without rewriting stuff ?

Thanks a lot of any help given !

Note: We want to keep a part of our codebase in NG1, because it's not feasable for us to convert all of it right now with the codebase we have.

Answer (score 1):

Angular's `UpgradeComponent` constructor calls this:

```js
private initializeOutputs() {
  // Initialize the outputs for `=` and `&` bindings
  this.bindings.twoWayBoundProperties.concat(this.bindings.expressionBoundProperties)
      .forEach(propName => {
        const outputName = this.bindings.propertyToOutputMap[propName];
        (this as any)[outputName] = new EventEmitter(); // <--- sets it to an EventEmitter
      });
}
```

which sets each `&` binding defined on your `bindings` object to an `EventEmitter` even if (unfortunately for you) the binding is optional and not currently assigned.

One thing you can do, though, is use the `$onChanges()` lifecycle hook in your NG1 component controller to help you identify which bindings have been assigned and which have not been.

This hook fires before `$onInit()` and gets called with an object that holds the changes of all one-way bindings with the currentValue and the previousValue.

This means that the object has a property only for each binding that's been assigned a value. So in your case, that "changes" object will have `username` and `onInit` properties but *will not* have an `onAction` property.

There are different ways you can leverage that, of course, but one simple approach would be like so:

Create an `assignedBindings` member on your controller and, in `$onChanges()`, assign it the `changes` object that gets passed in:

```js
// ng1DemoComponent MyController

assignedBindings;

public $onChanges(changes) {
  this.assignedBindings = changes;
}
```

So `this.assignedBindings` will look like this:

```js
{
  onInit: { previousValue: undefined, /* ... */ }, // <-- SimpleChange instance
  username: { previousValue: undefined, /* ... */ } // <-- SimpleChange instance
}
```

Then update `$onInit()` to check any of the bound properties that you would only want to be set to `EventEmitter`s if they were actually assigned, and set the properties to `null` if they're not assigned:

```js
// ng1DemoComponent MyController

public $onInit() {
  this.resultFromNg2 = this.onInit();

  if (!this.assignedBindings.onInit) { // <--- verify onInit assigned
    this.onInit = null;
  }

  if (!this.assignedBindings.onAction) { // <--- verify onAction assigned
    this.onAction = null;
  }

  this.onActionHasValue = this.onAction != null;
  this.typeOfOnAction = typeof this.onAction;
}
```

You might need to go further and check the `currentValue` of each of those `SimpleChange` instances if they could change over time, but you get the idea.

[Here's a fork of your StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hybrid-upgrade-a1l1zl?file=ng1%2Fng1-demo.component.ts) showing this approach. It might be a bit hacky but it seems to work.

Thanks for creating that StackBlitz, by the way—that helped tremendously in trying to look into this.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer on this !
The thing I don't understand through is that they put an `new EventEmitter` for every `&` bindings, however my `onInit` binding that has a return value works which normaly would not work with a `EventEmitter` so I'm kinda intrigued.